# How can we reduce the property proxying overhead of NHibernate?

Tags: performance, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, proxy, castle-dynamicproxy

We are using Fluent NHibernate 1.3.0.727 and NHibernate 3.3.0.4000 to map our properties to columns in the database. Here is an abbreviated sample of one of our ClassMaps:

```
    public class TankMap : ClassMap<Tank>
    {
        public TankMap()
        {
            Id(o => o.Id);
            Map(o => o.TankSystem);
        }
    }
```

In this case the TankSystem property is a **string**.

In parts of our application there is a lot of calculations that involve accessing the mapped properties (such as TankSystem) numerous times. When we profile the application, simply accessing these properties takes a up a considerable amount of time because each time they are accessed, it has to go through the NHibernate.Proxy.DefaultLazyInitializer.Intercept method.

We need to make our calculations as fast as possible and would like to avoid this proxying overhead. One approach is to copy the properties that we want (eg. TankSystem) into arrays and use the arrays any time we want to access this information, but then this is not a very object-oriented approach.

**Update:**

We have tried mapping our properties using Not.LazyLoad, for example:

```
Map(o => o.TankSystem).Not.LazyLoad();
```

However, this does not seem to have any effect on whether this property is actually proxied.

Is there any kind of option to avoid/reduce this proxying overhead?

Comment: NHibernate 3.x does not use Castle DynamicProxy. As such I think this question is mistagged

Answer (score 1):

Yes! `.Not.LazyLoad()` for the rescue!

```
    public TankMap()
    {
        Id(o => o.Id);
        Map(o => o.TankSystem).Not.LazyLoad();
    }
```

I found a good and short explanation about it:

> You might wonder what the Not.LazyLoad() means. By default Fluent NHibernate defines the mappings to use lazy load. But that also means that all properties of our entities would have to be virtual(Proxies).

[**source**](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Your-very-first-NHibernate-application-Part-1.aspx)

Comment: I had tried this approach but it didn't seem to make a difference - the TankSystem property was still getting proxied. We are using an older version of FluentNHibernate (1.2.0.712) so it might be that this change does  work in a later version - I will try upgrading to the latest version and see if it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach does not seem to do anything for us. Profiling with dotTrace still shows that invocations of the any No.LazyLoad properties still go through to the NHibernate.Proxy.DefaultLazyInitializer.Intercept method.

Comment: @GeoffHardy. But that doesn't say you get a proxy! When you update, write **Update** because your update made all the answer look stupid.

Answer (score 1):

I would really be careful of using .Not.LazyLoad() in your mappings and rather eager load in your queries as needed. Problems can rise if lazyload fetch strategies are not correctly configured. Always best to check every query with a tool like NHProf.

Linq:

```
var tanks = _session.Linq<Tank>()
               .Fetch(x=>x.TankSystem)
               .ToList();
```

QueryOver (My pref):
    var tanks = _session.QueryOver()
                   .Fetch(x=>x.TankSystem).Eager
                   .List();

```
TankSystem tankSystemAlias = null;
var tanks = _session.QueryOver<Tank>()
                .JoinAlias(x=>x.TankSystem, () => tankSystemAlias, JoinType.InnerJoin) // or JoinType.LeftOuterJoin
                .List()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid having virtual properties on object is:

```
public TankMap()
{
        Id(o => o.Id);
        this.Not.LazyLoad(); 
        Map(o => o.TankSystem);
}
```

This way there is no property proxy magic.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, it will make **all** the properties not lazyloaded, which can be a huge performance hit!

Comment: Yes it will and so none of the properties need to be virtual. It would only be a performance hit if some of the properties do need to be lazy loaded.

Comment: If you do that thing two many times, you can end up with the whole DB in memory after single row query. So I prefer setting the `.Not.LazyLoad()` on the `property` level instead of the `class` level.

Comment: The whole DB would only be loaded into memory if you have a very deep object graph and all entities can be reached by association from all others and this is bad design anyway. I've been trying to avoid lazy loading all together, instead focusing on keeping entities small.